# How to make all my external jquery files load properly for the Dom effects in partials to work in angular routing

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-routing

Hi I am working on a project where I have a web template theme which contains a lot of jquery files. I want to use angular in it. When I apply the angular routing by making partials out of its contents these jquery effects in my page are failing to work properly. So how to do angular routing the right way where a html page into which a partial is loaded contains a lot of external jquery files.​

I have tried using ocLazyLoad and Requirejs etc etc non of those are working which I found as solutions from stackoverflow.
Can any one tell the steps how to do it right way routing for it.

Answer (score 0):

This questions lacks of some details so i'll try to handle some possible case that might not concern you :

- If you use `script` tag in a template loaded by ngRouter it won't work.
- If you're jQuery is triggering whenever document (the javascript object) is Loaded, it won't work, because partials as not loaded yet.

> So how to do angular routing the right way where a html page into which a partial is loaded contains a lot of external jquery files.​

Well since it's still a braod way of describing what you have i can only give you some generals way :

- Listen for route events to trigger your jQuery at the right time : `$routeChangeSuccess` will be your friend
- Wrap jQuery in directives. For instance, i don't use ui-bootstrap so i wrapped the bootstrap component that i needed like this :

---

```
module.directive('ngToggle', ['$log', function($log){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
         if (attrs.ngToggle=="tooltip"){
                $(element).tooltip();
              }
         ...
       }
    }
```